# Does the microcontroller need to support a given filesystem in USB Mass Storage Class scenario?

Tags: usb, avr, nand, fat

I've been thinking about designing a small flash drive of sorts with the [AT32UC3A3256](http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT32UC3A3256.aspx). I'm planning on using e.MMC managed NAND which I can hook up to the MCU without a problem. Just wondering does the MCU need to support a given filesystem exFAT or FAT32, or is that simply OS based?

Comment: That's OS based.

Comment: I'd say that if the MCU is not accessing that filesystem (to read/write data) then it does not even **need** to know which filesystem is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSD is a block device emulation. The host OS (PC) requests raw blocks of data. It is the OS that then places a filesystem over those blocks.

That is why you can format a flash drive to NTFS, FAT32, ext3, etc, and even partition it up.

Comment: Also note, that you do not need to use any filesystem actually and you can use it as "block device" or kind of "block memory", so you just write some values (of your choise) at some offsets (your choise) and be able to retriev them later. Only it needs to be in some blocks ("sectors") as you cannot write just one sigle byte (but you can read the block, change the byte(s) and save the block back). So it is up to you, if you will use it just so "flat", or use some popular filesystem or invent your own. You can do the same to any harddisck, floppy disk and similar media. Depends on your needs.